# can we use csv file to get the data in cucumber

Tags: serenity-bdd

Can we use csv file to get data in cucumber?

By using

```
@RunWith(SerenityParameterizedRunner.class)
@UseTestDataFrom(value="testdata/status-levels.csv")
```

It is asking for `@Test`
as we should not use test in cucumber.

Can any one tell me how to read a file from csv file in cucumber?

Comment: Please use upper case and interpuction. Read "how to ask" in the help section.

Comment: moved annotations in code blocks. Added some capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Transformer](https://static.javadoc.io/info.cukes/cucumber-core/1.2.5/cucumber/api/Transformer.html) class. You need to customize your transformer and then use it in your stepdefinition.